# Having two titles in js charts

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, jscharts

https://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-doughnut-chart/

I already used the title property inside my js chart (in the middle of the doughnut ) But I was wondering if i can add a title (text) on top of the chart as well !
how can I achieve that?

Comment: Wrapping the chart in a div and add a text?

Comment: Please include an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you've done so far.

Comment: @Ruba Suliman, the link in your question refers to canvas.js not chart.js